# Python Tkinter: Entry-get giving wierd outputs

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying out the tkinter entry command to get entry. Something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


myInput = Entry(root)
myInput.grid(row=4, column=0)

def buttonClick2():
    label2 = Label(root, text = myInput.get)
    label2.grid(row=6, column=0)


otherButton = Button(root, text="Enter", padx=20 ,pady =10, command= buttonClick2)
otherButton.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

But while running the program, when I press the button, it displays a random (probably)  13 digit number with `get` at the end, in the `label2`, something like:

```
2068946574615get
```

Furthermore it increments by 512 every time I press the button. What is happening and how do I get it to print the input in the `myInput` entry?

Comment: `text=myInput.get` => `text=myInput.get()`. Next time try `print`ing the text before passing it in and checking if it looks good.

Comment: @TheLizzard  Thanks that was a lifesaver. I'd definitely try printing from the next time.